# $e^x$ defined $a^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have read the chapter up and down but I do not see how, I would like to not take anything from the book but start on e fresh example as I think that would help me to realise what is going on.

Im struggling to see how

$e^x$ 
is defined for all real x to define the arbitrary exponential

$a^x$
(where a>0) for all real x

Could someone show the connection

This is what is stated:

I have been shown this in the book: If r is rational $\text{Ln}\left(a^r\right)=r \text{Ln}(a)$, therefore: $a^r=e^{\text{rLn}(a)}$, I understand the first part($\text{Ln}\left(a^r\right)=r \text{Ln}(a)$), but I do not understand:

therefore $a^r=e^{\text{rLn}(a)}$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$a^x=e^{x(\ln a)}$. This is how $a^x$ is defined in general.

Comment: I have been shown this in the book: If r is rational $\text{Ln}\left(a^r\right)=r \text{Ln}(a)$, therefore: $a^r=e^{\text{rLn}(a)}$, I understand the first part($\text{Ln}\left(a^r\right)=r \text{Ln}(a)$), but I do not understand therefore .....

Comment: If $\ln x= y$ then $x= e^y$- this is by the definition of $\ln$.